# LaTeX flashcard problem

Tags: macros, flashcards

I use a package to make flashcards which has the formatting `\card{#1}{#2}`, where `#1` and `#2` represent the front and back side. The package works great.

I like to block out text, so I have made newcommands `\frontcard`, which blocks out the text using highlighting or underlining and makes the text white, and `\backcard`, which is essentially a dummy command that replaces frontcard. For example, I would have to write `\card{The chancellor of Germany is \frontcard{Angela Merkel}}{The chancellor of Germany is \backcard{Angela Merkel}}`.

```
\documentclass[frontgrid]{flacards}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\frontcard}[1]{\textcolor{yellow}{\colorbox{yellow}{$#1$}}}
\newcommand{\backcard}[1]{#1} 

\begin{document}

\pagesetup{2}{4} 


\card{The chancellor of \frontcard{Germany} is \frontcard{Angela Merkel}. }{The chancellor of \backcard{Germany} is \backcard{Angela Merkel}. }

\end{document}
```

What I would like to reduce 2 newcommands to one command, as writing two commands is a little redundant.

I can't think of an easy way to do this though, because of the arbitrary number of blank fields (2 or more). So something like:

`\newcard{The chancellor of \blank{Germany} is \blank{Angela Merkel}}`

I was thinking how I could accomplish this; maybe with the `ifthen` package or `etoolbox` package? So, if I'm in `#1` do this command, if I'm in `#2` then do the other command. However I can't figure out how to implement this exactly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why can't you use `\frontcard` in both arguments of `\card`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. Note that you can mark inline code by using backticks (`), as I've done in your post.

Comment: Can you please add to your question a minimal, complete, and compilable example showing your settings and the involved commands in action?

Comment: @Gonzalo. because the front is blacked out and the back gives the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this:

```
\documentclass[frontgrid]{flacards}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\frontcard}[1]{\textcolor{yellow}{\colorbox{yellow}{$#1$}}}
\newcommand{\backcard}[1]{#1} 

% new:
\newcommand{\Card}[1]{% create new command for cards with blanks
    \card{% call the original \card command with twice the same argument (#1)
        \let\blank\frontcard% but let \blank behave like \frontcard the first time
        #1
    }{%
        \let\blank\backcard% and like \backcard the second time
        #1
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\pagesetup{2}{4} 


\card{The chancellor of \frontcard{Germany} is \frontcard{Angela Merkel}. }{The chancellor of \backcard{Germany} is \backcard{Angela Merkel}. }

\Card{The ``Altkanzler'' of \blank{Germany} is \blank{Helmut Kohl}. }

\end{document}
```

Note that I used `\frontcard` and `\backcard` in my definition of `\Card`

---

There are also ways to get this with an `\if` construct or even the `ifthen` package but thats an overkill I think. The above is the easiest solution I could imagin, exept that one can put the definition of `\frontcard` and `\backcard` in the definition of `\Card`

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly! Ill upvote when I have enough rep

Comment: @michael: OK. Please note, that I added some explanations to my code …